# Does Google PageSpeed Insights have nothing to do with where my server is?

Tags: seo, page-speed, google-pagespeed

Here is the Page Speed Insight:
https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/

I sometimes run my website on it but ALWAYS get the same result. However, I used to think this is very reasonable because I have the same website code so every test would get the same result.

But why doesn't Google ask for a test location? For instance, on https://www.webpagetest.org/ it would ask you from where do you want to test the speed website.

Why not Google Page Speed ask that? If I get a low score, does that mean I only need to take care of my code and there's nothing to do with my server location?

FYI: I have this confusion after testing my web page with webpagetest.org and the score is almost perfect with Japan testings while very normal with US testings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Google Insights considers [page response time](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/Server) as a factor and it's a known fact that the distance between a server to another increases latency as the distance in which the packets need to travel, therefore it the response time is naturally decreased.

Also... note that the scoring used on other sites are not the same as that of Google Insights, each use their own scoring system so that you simply can't compare one to another.

Google does not use Insights to rank your website and the scoring that you see can be useless because a website with a poor score on a very fast server can easily response faster than a website with a great score on a slow server. All that matters is that your content is fast and compatible with the major of users visiting the site.

Google Insights, is insights, it's not that important, ensure that the majors are fixed and then focus on the response and rendering time in the country or area that you are targetting.

Answer (score 1):

The response time of the server (the only speed measured) doesn't have anything with distance to do. Server response time is the time from the server gets pinged to it responds.

Google has set the max limit for server response time down at 200 ms. Anything beyond that is too high.

Just to make it clear, server response time is not your page load time. Google Page Speed Insights does not measure page load time currently.

Depending on your hosting solution and how much control you have on it, you can optimize but there are always limits for optimizations.

However, don't bother thinking about that. It's much more important that your pages load for under 3 sec to avoid high bounce rate. And it is a combination of factors that helps there.

Comment: Thanks Diana. I would like to know, how can Google get the "the time from the server gets pinged to it responds" if it doesn't have anything to do with geolocation?

Comment: Well, think of it this way: the request travels to wherever your server is. Once the server is located, it gets pinged. From this point on the time starts running until the server responds. Sort of like a handshake or hello, enabling the further communication. Not until the respond is sent back to the requester's location